# NaN issue with cost function

Tags: angular

Hello I have been teaching myself angular and I have built a simple shopping cart app. I have managed to replace a simple array to use data from an API instead thanks to someone on this website for helping me with the final part of it. I have noticed an issue once I made the change that the total cost of the shopping cart returns NaN, I'm guessing there is an issue with something having the same name therefore throwing up the issue however I can't seem to spot it. any help would be appreciated and I have linked my full project below and I pasted in the two areas where I believe the issue could be. when I console log this.products it returns with undefined so I believe that could be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your price for a product is represented as a string (i.e "$4.04"). JavaScript doesn't know how to add them together. So in order to get an actual number you would have to strip the "$" with the function .substring():

```
  calcPrice() {
    return this.products.reduce((acc, prod) => {
      if (this.calcTotal() >= 10) {
        return (acc += prod.price.substring(1) * prod.num * 0.5);
      } else if (this.calcTotal() >= 5) {
        return (acc += prod.price.substring(1) * prod.num * 0.75);
      } else {
        return (acc += prod.price.substring(1) * prod.num);
      }
    }, 0);
  }
```